# Asyncio. Закрыть сокет из другой задачи

Tags: python, asyncio

Приветствие.
Начал изучать библиотеку Asyncio, разбираю пример с простым TCP-сервером асинхронным. Есть задачка добавить в него таймаут, по окончанию которого клиентский сокет будет закрыт. Для этого я вызываю create_task-ом корутину, которая отсчитывает какое то время, после чего делает сокет.close. Но при этом сервер вызывает исключение, с которым мне непонятно что делать.

```py
import asyncio
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 50000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setblocking(False)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)

async def conn_timeout(conn):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('timeOut!')
    conn.close()

async def handler(conn):
    task_tm = asyncio.create_task(conn_timeout(conn))
    while True:
        print('wait for data for')
        msg = await loop.sock_recv(conn, 1024)
        if not msg:
            break

        await loop.sock_sendall(conn, msg)
        #conn.close()
    print('close')
    conn.close()

async def server():
    while True:
        conn, addr = await loop.sock_accept(s)
        loop.create_task(handler(conn))

loop.create_task(server())
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

При вызове conn.close() я получаю(под Win7)

```
python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\raznoe\mine\!Справочная инфа\IT\python\practice\async\servexampl.py", line 37, in <module>
    loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 539, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1739, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\selectors.py", line 323, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\selectors.py", line 314, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом
```

Под Ubuntu18

```
python
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<handler() done, defined at servexampl.py:19> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x7f7028faca08>()]>>
```

Перехватить исключение у меня получается лишь в

> loop.run_forever()

но при этом петля схлапывается, все подключения в ней теряются. В handler сокет закрывается в самом конце, я так понимаю, обращений к нему больше нет, поэтому все ок. Я пробовал отменить задачу handler из conn_timeout, но соединение остается, текущий клиент не "отваливается".

Спасибо!

Comment: А что не воспользовался серверами из асинкио?

Comment: При использовании корутины create_server сокет действительно закрывается без ошибки, видимо, это исключение перехватывается и корректно обрабатывается, но я использую работу с сокетами, потому что мне нужно также добавить использование потоков - я создаю пул потоков и в отдельных потоках вызываю accept для серверного сокета. С create_server я не знаю, как такое провернуть, разве что отдельно каждый сервер в отдельный поток, но это немного не то, что мне нужно. В приведенном коде я для упрощения убрал работу с потоками, оставил по минимуму.

Comment: Всё думал над этой задачкой и не пойму зачем тут потоки. просто все блокирующие вызовы викидывай в тред пул экзекутор, а ацепт можно и в одном треде делать..